# Two label printer installed on same computer become too slow after about one month

Tags: printing, slowdown

I use PrintDialog printvisual to print to two thermal label printer that installed on same computer. After about one month, printing speed become too slow.

I try several ways as following but can not solve the problem:

- Restart print spooler.
- Restart computer and printer.
- Reinstall driver.
- Use different brand between them.
  The only way can help is reinstall Window
  Please guide me how to solve that problem. Thank you

Comment: This is unlikely to be a programming problem. If it is, it would likely need physical access to your hardware to resolve.